# Can't install a signed component in the GAC?

Tags: c#, clr, versioning, gac

I try to install a strongly-signed component in the GAC by using drag-drop to the C:\WINDOWS\assembly directory but nothing happens
No error messages, no entry added... nothing!

gacutil -I doesn't work either.

Even when I drag-drop a non signed assembly, I don't get an error message that should say , "Assembly is not strongly signed". Just nothing happening.

Why not?

Additional info:

I added following 2 lines in my component

```
[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]

[assembly: System.Reflection.AssemblyKeyFile("ScientificToolsLib.snk")]
```

I have created the strong keyfile and everything builds just fine.
Double checking with ildasm I see the key appearing in the manifest.

But still, I can't install it in the GAC???

thank you

Chris

Comment: And all I can think when I see your questions is: Three question marks where none is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a .Net 4.0 assembly? The 4.0 GAC is under "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly".

Comment: @Chris No problem, simple things like this can get us all sometimes.